# Pass the data from a tag of masterpage to normal web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How can i pass any data or multiple values from html a tag of any master page to any of the web form in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

Client Side:

Put a hidden field in master page, set whatever value you want to save in it and using hidden fields id, you can get the desired value in any pages, provided master page is referenced.

Server Side:

Place the value in any server control,(textbox, label, hidden) set the style sheet to display:none (so that the control is not visible in the form) and then using FindControl method of C# you can access the value.

If the above answers help you, vote me up.

Comment: yeaah..it sounds interesting.